# How to Execute Network background in ios4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

Our app does not use the default email app for emailing, instead uses an SMTP implementation. Right now when the app is in foreground - the email gets sent using the SMTP connection. But say if I hit send and then switch to another application - the email is not getting sent. It is sent only when we resume back to the app. Typically we are looking to send the email when the app is in backgrond as well. Any tips are welcome. How are chat applications polling for new messages - if we get any tips around this - we can accomplish our task as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.

According to the Apple documentation about Multi Tasking:

> In addition to the preceding keys, iOS
>   provides two other ways to do work in
>   the background:
>
> **Task completion** — applications can ask
>   the system for extra time to complete
>   a given task.
>  **Local
>   notifications** — applications can
>   schedule local notifications to be
>   delivered at a predetermined time.

If your task is not a long and continuous task, such as a VOIP service, GPS service or Audio  service, you can declare it as "finite length task" and you can complete this task in the background. Remember that the MU is available only from iOS 4.0 and only for 3GS and 4 devices. You should also manage those tasks for other devices that don't support the MU.

Always according to the official documentation, you can do that:

> You can use task completion to ensure
>   that important but potentially
>   long-running operations do not end
>   abruptly when the user leaves the
>   application. **For example, you might
>   use this technique to save user data
>   to disk or finish downloading an
>   important file from a network server.**
>   There are a couple of design patterns
>   you can use to initiate such tasks:
>
> - Wrap any long-running critical tasks
>     with
>     `-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]`
>     and `-[UIApplication endBackgroundTask:]` calls. This
>     protects those tasks in situations
>     where your application is suddenly
>     moved to the background.
> - Wait for your
>     application delegate’s
>     `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method
>     to be called and start one or more
>     tasks then.

Comment: Tasks wrapped in `beginBackgroundTask…` and `endBackgroundTask:` are allowed to continue execution for approximately 10 minutes in the background. Should be enough to complete a small download and similar.

Answer (score -3):

One of the apple's requirements to third party apps is that you cannot run your app in the background. I think, you can do your task by returning NO in your applicationShouldTerminate method, but your app will not be approved by apple to be posted in AppStore.

Comment: In general you can't run in the background, however the question is about _finishing_ doing something when the app exits which you can do -- it's called "Task Completion."